# Safari ignores cache control

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, safari, browser-cache

I built an image resize script to resize the requested image and return it with PHP. However I would like to cache the requested images.

I tried to built some .htaccess rules and realized cache-control is not working in safari for me. Safari caches .css files, etc. automatically but does not cache images. I do not have any website specific developer tools active, and tested this in a blank environment with an extra subdomain with only a .htaccess and a .jpeg file.

My .htaccess code looks like:

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=10800,private"
```

With nothing else in it which should force all files to be cached for 3 hours. With Chrome however this works as expected and caches the files. Server returns a http header 304 telling the client to load the file from the cache. 
Taking a look at the safari file informations in the developer menu, I can see the Cache-Control settings are received well (Cache-Control: max-age=10800,private) but on each reload safari shows a http 200 response without any cached files and loads the image again.

Are there any known issues with safari cache control? I searched the web but did not find anything and my web hosting provider told me caching is nothing browser specific on server side.